# Trying to Alternate Row Color in PHP

Tags: php, function, html-table

I'm looking to alternate row colors using PHP function.  Here's what I have (although it does not work):

```
function row($year) {
    if($year%2) 
        $color == "#FFF";
    else
        $color == "#000";
}

for ($year=2013; $year<=2023; $year++) 
    {
    row($year);
    echo "<tr bgcolor='$color'><td>$year</td><td>$tdate</td></tr>";
    }
```

Basically, if a year is odd I would like the color of the row to be white.  If even, black.

Comment: Use CSS for this sort of thing. Defining zebra stripes in your PHP code is soooo 2003.

Comment: Your `$color` variable is discarded after `row` returns; use a return value instead. And use a class name instead of `bgcolor`. @SDC: IE <= 8 doesn't support `nth-child`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel - Use either [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) or [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/) to back-port `nth-child` to old IE. Or just let IE users go without the stripes -- it won't kill them not to have stripes.

Comment: Would all of this advice be soooo 2013 now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [From W3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html)
>
> 15.1.1 Background color - `bgcolor`  attribute has been deprecated in favor of style sheets for specifying background color information.

now what should you do is

```
function row($year) {
    return ($year % 2 == 0) ? "#FFFFFF" : "#000000";
}

for ($year = 2013; $year <= 2023; $year++) {
    echo "<tr style='background-color:".row($year).";'><td>$year</td><td>$tdate</td></tr>";
}
```

however its looks like you are not aware of what `==` does  its a equal to operator its not assignment operator

what assignment operator do is assign right hand side value to left hand for example

> [image]

what [Comparison Operators(`==`)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) do is

```
$a == $b    Equal   TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
```

second you also there is the scope of a variable

> The [**scope of a variable**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) is the context within which it is defined. For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well.
>
> above is quoted from php manual to read more [**check this**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 11):

Why don't you just use CSS with the [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child) selector?

```
tr:nth-child( 2n ) {
  background-color: #000;
}
tr:nth-child( 2n + 1 ) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Then no further attributes are needed on the `<tr>` element.

Besides the IE, most browsers support this. See the [Browser compatibility of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: This is best approach IMO.  Keep the styling logic in CSS.

Comment: +1 Use CSS wherever you can, it removes (view related) complexity from your code and allows for more flexible styling.

Comment: +1. Even IE can be made to support this using tools like Selectivizr.

Comment: "Besides the IE" is an under-statement. Trying to make it work it work in IE(using various other hacks/plugs) will be an overkill for something as simple as this, imo.

Comment: @Pushpesh - not true. Either [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) or [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/) makes it easy. Or just let IE users go without the stripes -- it won't kill them not to have stripes.

Comment: @SDC I agree, just wanted to highlight it. Btw, its a great solution. +1 from me. :)

Comment: who cares IE its nothing more than piece of carp from Microsoft however its good solution since its reduce load on server plus +1 for the shake of reducing server load and get rid of **deprecated bgcolor**

Comment: I understand there's probably a better way of doing it, I was just curious what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
function row($year) {
    $color = '';
    if($year%2) 
        $color = "#FFF";
    else
        $color = "#000";

   return $color;
}

for ($year=2013; $year<=2023; $year++) 
    {
    $color = row($year);
    echo "<tr bgcolor='$color'><td>$year</td><td>$tdate</td></tr>";
    }
```

Comment: @JebThomas Please see the updated answer. Also, check if `$tdate` exists, else it will give a warning. You had used `==` in the function instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($year=2013; $year<=2023; $year++) 
{
    echo "<tr bgcolor='".$year%2==0?"#fff":"#000"."'><td>$year</td><td>$tdate</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't saving the result of your function anywhere. Try this:

```
function row($year) {
    if($year%2) 
        $color == "#FFF";
    else
        $color == "#000";
}

for ($year=2013; $year<=2023; $year++) 
{
    $color = row($year);
    echo "<tr bgcolor='$color'><td>$year</td><td>$tdate</td></tr>";
}
```

It's about variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

you are not returning anything from function,do like this

```
function row($year) {
    if($year%2) 
        $color == "#FFF";
    else
        $color == "#000";
return $color;
}

for ($year=2013; $year<=2023; $year++) 
    {
    $color = row($year);
    echo "<tr bgcolor='$color'><td>$year</td><td>$tdate</td></tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like other programming languages, you have to know when you're working with local variables and globals. In this case, you're trying to use a variable in one function that is local to another.

```
function row($year) {
    if($year%2 == 1) 
        return "#FFF";
    else
       return "#000";
}

for ($year=2013; $year<=2023; $year++) 
    {
    echo "<tr bgcolor='".row($year)."'><td>$year</td><td>$tdate</td></tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$host=""; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$dbname=""; // Database name
$tblname=""; // Table name
// Connect to server and select databse
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tblname";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// Define $color=1
$color="1";
echo '<h3 align = "center">Employee Details <hr /></h3>';
echo '<table width="400" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">';
while($rows=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
// If $color==1 table row color = #FFCCFF
if($color == 1){
echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFCCFF'><td>$rows[0]</td><td>$rows[1]</td><td>$rows[2]</td><td>$rows[3]</td></tr>";
// Set $color==2, for switching to other color
$color="2";
}
// When $color not equal 1, table row color = #FFC600
else {
echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFC600'><td>$rows[0]</td><td>$rows[1]</td><td>$rows[2]</td><td>$rows[3]</td></tr>";
// Set $color back to 1
$color="1";
}
}
echo '</table>';
mysql_close();
?>
```

In the above coding,first we select the data from the database and then we define a variable $color with the value 1. After while loop an if condition is added.If $color=1 then table row color will be #FFCCFF and inside the if condition we set the $color==2 for switching to other color.Now when $color not equal to 1 then table row color= #FFC600 and else condition executes.Under the else condition we again set the $color back to 1.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.I added the explanation.